# How to mock local variables if present in more than one method

Tags: junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito and Junit.
Having trouble with adding tests for existing classes.

I am having on class with following 2 methods.
privateMethod and publicmethod
Publicmethod calls private method and has similar structure in terms of functionality as private method(i.e. get something from DB)

Now while testing it through mockito I am trying to do this

```
    Class MyClass {
        private String privateMethod(String number){
            String sql = null;
            java.sql.Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
            ResultSet rs1 = null;
            String returnString = "";
            try {
                conn = dbConnect();
                sql = " Select SomeCOL from SOME_TABLE";
                pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pst.setString(1, caseNumber);
                rs1 = pst.executeQuery();
                if(rs1.next())
                    returnString = rs1.getString(1);
            }catch (SQLException e) {
            } finally {
                //close conn
            }
            return returnString ;
        }
        public void publicmethod(String number){
            String retVal = privateMethod(number);
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(retVal)){
                String sql = null;
                java.sql.Connection conn1 = null;
                PreparedStatement pst = null;
                ResultSet rs1 = null;
                try {
                    conn1 = dbConnect();
                    sql = " SOME_SQL_STMNT";
                    pst = conn1.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs1 = pst.executeQuery();
                    while(rs1.next()){
                                     //do something
                    }
                }catch (SQLException e) {
                } finally {
                    //close conn
                }
            }   

        }
    }
```

Below is *Test class*:
Added donothing to skip call to the dbdisconnect method which assigns null to the conn (macking mock connection to null)

```
    Class MyclassTest {
    @InjectMocks
        private MyClass mc;

        @Mock
        java.sql.Connection mockConn;

        @Mock private PreparedStatement mockStatement;

        @Mock
        ResultSet rs;


        @Before
        public void setup(){
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        }
        try {

                when(mockConn.prepareStatement(" Select SomeCOL from SOME_TABLE")).thenReturn(mockStatement);
    when(mockStatement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(rs));
                when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
                when(rs.getString(1)).thenReturn("123");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
            }
```

Now when I run these test I can see that Connection is mocked at privatemethod and I can see that value returned is "123"(Tried with throwing manual exception with message as returnvalue). However in public method I am getting

> Nullpointer at line 
>   pst = conn1.prepareStatement(sql);
>   as conn1 is null.

Is there something wrong.
Can we handle this ?

Updated Code for Super class of MyClass having Dbconnect method

```
public java.sql.Connection dbConnect (String dbname) {
        DSname = "SOME_DSLOOKUPNAME";
        InitialContext ctx = null;
        if (connection == null) {
            try {
                Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<>();
                ht.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "PROVIDER_PORT");
                ctx = new InitialContext(ht);
                javax.sql.DataSource ds = (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup(DSname);
                connection = ds.getConnection();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return (connection);
    }
```

**Final Working Test Implementation**

```
Class MyclassTest {
@InjectMocks
    private MyClass mc;

    @Mock
    java.sql.Connection mockConn;

    @Mock private PreparedStatement mockStatement;

    @Mock
    ResultSet rs;
@Spy
MyClass mc1;



    @Before
    public void setup(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
@Test
public void publicMethodTest(){
    try {
           Mockito.doReturn(mockConn).when(mc1).dbConnect(Mockito.anyString());
        when(mockConn.prepareStatement(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockStatement).thenReturn(mockStatement);
        doNothing().when(mc1).dbDisconnect();

        when(mockStatement.executeQuery()).thenReturn(rs).thenReturn(rs);
        when(rs.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
        when(rs.getString(1)).thenReturn("123");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }
mc1.publicMethod("12345678");
}
```

Comment: The Connection should be a field of `MyClass` else you cant really mock it like this. Other People tend to override a getConnection() method they have in their classes. -- I personally find this isn`t really a case where one should use mocking as this requires an Integration Test anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to have a way to inject connection object in your MyClass through some constructor or setter method. so you can mock things.

```
public class  MyClass {
private Connection connection;

public MyClass(Connection connection) {
  this.connection = connection;
}
....
....

}
```

and in your unit test, you can mock something like this :

```
    @Test
    public void testConnection() {
    Connection mockConnection = mock(Connection.class);
    when(mockConnection.prepareStatment("select statements")).thenReturn(mockStatement);
     MyClass myClass = new MyClass(mockConnection);
    myClass.publicMethod();
 }
```

Comment: Accepting this answer because it outlines the thing that Mock doesent work on local method variables, Instead it mocks class Member variables. Updated above final working Test

Answer (score 0):

The method `prepareStatement` is called with different parameters value in `privateMethod()` and `publicMethod()`. So you should either:

Mock distinctly each call:

```
when(mockConn.prepareStatement(" Select SomeCOL from SOME_TABLE")).thenReturn(mockStatement);
when(mockConn.prepareStatement(" SOME_SQL_STMNT")).thenReturn(mockStatement);
```

Or have a more general mock:

```
when(mockConn.prepareStatement(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockStatement);
```

Comment: Yes. I tried that however same issue. I think its not the issue with  prepatestatement call. As We have mocked Connection object, This is being mapped to local variable in Private method and is prepopulated.
However at public method its null

Comment: Can you show the method `dbConnect()` ? Mockito can only member variable, not local variable.

Comment: Actually MyClass is Extending Another Class "DBConnection" and this super class is having Implementation .Updated Super class above in description

Comment: I see. Answer from @Pradeep seems to be a good starting point to me.

Comment: I think I am in better shape now as I figured it out. in finally block of private method Code is resetting connection to null (Call to dbdisconnect).
Is there a way to reinitialize connection mock object when some method is called on it?